# Analytic function having countable number of singularities in the unit circle but analytic at all other points in the extended plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am solving a problem in the book "Complex Analysis" by Ahlfors. The problem reads as follows: For what values of z is $\sum\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$ convergent?

By considering various cases, I am able to prove the following:

1. For 0$\le|z|<1$, the given series is convergent.
2. For |z|>1, the given series is convergent.
3. At $\infty$ the given series is convergent.
4. On the unit circle, the function has countable number of poles.

For proving 2, I majorize the nth term of the series by $\frac{2}{z^n}$ and conclude convergence by Comparison test.

z=1/w gives the same series and hence I conclude 1 and 3.

The substitution z=$e^{i\theta}$ gives countable poles at $\frac{2n+1}{2}\times\pi$

Are my conclusions correct?

Is the radius of convergence for the given series 1?

If the radius of convergence is 1, the series must be unbounded outside |z|>1 which contradicts 2.

Where's the catch? Or is my working wrong somewhere?

Please help.

Comment: You can’t speak of the radius of convergence as the series is not an entire series as it is written.

Comment: Note that if $|z|=1$ the general term of the series is not convergent to zero so the series cannot converge; this is an example of a holomorphic function that is defined by the same "formula" but has values in distinct connected components that are not connected to each other even in a weak sense - as $f$ is not given by a power series, but by a sum of analytic functions, the power series intuition doesn't work

Comment: @Conrad Thank you. Poles on the unit circle are not countable in number but only two poles at i and -i. I calculated wrong as countable.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The radius of convergence when the given function is expressed as a power series about 0 is 1. I agree the given expression is not a power series.